# What is the most efficient way to loop through a list and set max value Python?

Tags: python, list, performance, iteration, max

Say I have a list:

`my_list = [0.1, 0.14, 0.1, 0.03, 0.3, 0.01, 0.6]`

And I want to limit the max value to 0.2 so the wanted result is:

`my_list`

`[0.1, 0.14, 0.1, 0.03, 0.2, 0.01, 0.2]`

I tried

`[0.2 if x>0.2 else x for x in my_list]`

And also

`list(map(lambda x: min(x,0.2),my_list))`

The first one was found about 5-10 %  more efficient, but still too slow.

Is there any more time/complexity efficient way?

Comment: Have you tried using numpy with `np.clip(my_list, a_max=0.2)` ?

Comment: Time complexity wise, no there is not more efficient way. This has to be linear time. If you have to work with Python lists, there is probably nothing significantly faster than either approach. However, if you work with `numpy`, you can use `numpy` to do this sort of thing much, much faster.

Comment: `[x for x in my_list if x < 0.2] + [0.2]` ? BTW, if you care about efficiency, you shouldn't be using Python...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of time complexity, there is no more efficient way. This has to be linear time. If you have to work with Python lists, there is probably nothing *significantly* faster than the approaches you have here. However, if you work with `numpy`, you can use `numpy` to do this sort of thing much, much faster.

```
In [2]: my_list = [0.1, 0.14, 0.1, 0.03, 0.3, 0.01, 0.6]*10_000

In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: my_array = np.array(my_list)

In [5]: %timeit [0.2 if x>0.2 else x for x in my_list]
   ...:
2.52 ms ± 14.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit my_array.clip(max=0.2)
89.7 µs ± 1.27 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

So as you see, 89.7 µs / 2.52 ms == 0.0356, so using numpy, it takes only about 3-4% the amount of time it would take with a list, IOW it is **27-times faster**.

And just to show you they are doing the same thing:

```
In [8]: [0.2 if x>0.2 else x for x in my_list]
Out[8]: [0.1, 0.14, 0.1, 0.03, 0.2, 0.01, 0.2]

In [9]: my_array = np.array(my_list)

In [10]: my_array
Out[10]: array([0.1 , 0.14, 0.1 , 0.03, 0.3 , 0.01, 0.6 ])

In [11]: my_array.clip(max=0.2)
Out[11]: array([0.1 , 0.14, 0.1 , 0.03, 0.2 , 0.01, 0.2 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

The most pythonic solution was:

In [3]: %timeit **[min(x,0.2) for x in my_list]**
10.5 ms ± 302 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Fast (but lost some readability)

In [4]: %timeit **[x if x <0.2 else 0.2 for x in my_list]**
2.18 ms ± 11.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

If you have lots of data and can use a numeric library like numpy,
see @juampa response